# How to add new column in existing table uaing jdbc pyspark python?

Tags: python, mysql, jdbc, pyspark

Is this possible to add new column to existing table without overwriting on it ?
So if in table there is col1 , I want to add col2. So after .save() there will be col1 and col2 together, and not only overwritten col2.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try 'SELECT col2 from your_table'. If that gives you an error then col2 doesn't exist (assuming everything else is OK). Another way is with an ALTER TABLE statement where you attempt to add col2. If col2 exists, then that will fail

Answer (score 0):

See alter syntax

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html

use a `spark.sql(query)`

with

f. e.  `ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD columns (LastName string, DOB timestamp);`

Comment: Is this possible to do the same with jdbc connector and pyspark ? Without native mysql ? Thank you.

Comment: no i don't know of any there only limited functions anyhow that is why you can use ddl